# Rotate entire AR session axes (to align with real-world North-West-Up)

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, arkit, axes

I am trying to apply a rotation to my *entire* AR session so that the AR session world coordinates line up with north-west-up of the real world. I am using Xcode 12.0.1. I’ve tried to Google this but not finding what I’m looking for. Any help or pointing to the correct topics is greatly appreciated.  (Is there a different place to post this?)

I have a function that takes in real-world latitude/longitude/altitude coordinates and returns X-Y-Z.  These X-Y-Z values seem to work correctly.  That is when a lat/lon is north of me (in the real world) the sphere I draw in AR is on the positive X-axis (of the session’s world axis), and a lat/lon to the west of me is on the positive Y-axis. So far, so good.

The next step is to get the AR Session world coordinate axes (X-Y-Z) to line up with the real world north-west-up axes.  From seeing the coordinate system when the session starts (X and Z in the horizontal plane, Y up) it seems like I should just do two simple rotations: -pi/2 around X to get Y in the horizontal plane and Z up, followed by some rotation about the new Z to get X pointing north.

I have an ARSCNView inside of my UIViewController.  I have a configuration:

```
 private let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
```

And in viewDidLoad() I set debug options to show the session’s coordinates

```
self.asSceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin, … ]
```

Later (after viewDidLoad), via a button tap, I call a func that 1) gets the camera transform, 2) applies a rotation to the transform, and 3) uses the resultant rotated transform to set the world origin.

```
guard let transform = self.arSceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform else {… }
let newMat = SCNMatrix4Rotate( SCNMatrix4( transform ), minus90, 1, 0, 0) // minus90 is in radians
self.arSceneView.session.setWorldOrigin( relativeTransform: sind_float4x4( newMat) )
```

The result is some weirdly rotated/translated world axes.  Not too surprising that it doesn’t work the way I think it should but in order to debug it and understand it I need a better understanding of the process.

Question 1: camera.transform vs setWorldOrigin?
What is the connection/relationship between the camera transform and the worldOrigin? I get and print the camera.transform throughout the rotation process and the camera.transform never changes — even after setting the worldOrigin with a different transformation matrix.

Question 2: When is camera.transform set and how do you know?
All the way through viewWillLoad(0 and through viewDidLoad() I check on …camera.transform and it is always nil.  I added a button to check it (and rotate it) after the session starts (when it is not nil). I’m sure there is a better way. When is it set and what is the correct way to know when it is set?

Question 3: Any other advice on rotating the AR session?
Is my approach totally off?  Is there a different methodology I should be using? What other topics or key words should I be looking for?

Thank you,
Rick

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I have not found a way to change the ARKit camera transform, and you are not supposed to change the transform of the rootNode (according to Apple), so I solved my particular problem by inserting a node (I call it myRootNode) between the ARKit rootNode and the rest of my scene.  All my drawn element nodes are attached to myRootNode or children of myRootNode.  I apply rotations to myRootNode and then everything in the scene is rotated (except the ARKit WorldAxes so I draw my own in addition).

To get the ARKit coordinates (which are set when the ARSCNView session is run) to align with X north, Y west, and Z up I use the following rotations:

```
// point X-axis in the right direction
let yRot = appleHeadingAtRunRad + Double.pi/2.0
var mat = SCNMatrix4Rotate(SCNMatrix4Identity, Float(yRot), 0, 1, 0)

// put Y-axis in plane parallel to ground, Z up
let xRot = -Double.pi/2.0
mat = SCNMatrix4Rotate(mat, Float(xRot), 1, 0, 0)
myRootNode.transform = mat
```